# Is there a way to present multiple means in ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the code that I am using:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df_xy, aes(as.factor(x = Vehicle), y = accuracy)) + 
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Analyzer)) + 
stat_boxplot(aes(fill = Analyzer), geom = 'errorbar') + 
stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "point", shape = 20, size = 2, color = "red", fill = "red")
```

I present accuracy of 2 different analyzers vs vehicle type on x-axis.
I have 2 boxplots (not for all vehicles) and I want to show also two mean values with dots (and not only median). How can I do that? Below is example of my plot.

[image]

Comment: I am having a bit of an issue understanding what you are trying to do.
Are you trying to achieve the image you provided?

Nevertheless, if you have the values externally, you could map the manually with geom_hline(yintercept = mean1)

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to have separate means for blue and red boxplots (by Analyzers) for each vehicle. Now I have only 1 mean that is calculated by taking in account both red and blue results (you can see that mean as red points). I can try to do that externally as you suggested and then with 2 geom_hline, but I don't know if they will be placed inside of boxplots (one mean inside of blue and second inside of red) or in the middle like now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could include some sample data so that we could verify an answer.  However, it looks like you need to tell `stat_summary` how to group the data for the `mean` calculation and then to space the points horizontally.  The code probably should be

```
p1 <- ggplot(df_xy, aes(as.factor(x = Vehicle), y = accuracy)) + 
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Analyzer)) + 
stat_boxplot(aes(fill = Analyzer), geom = 'errorbar') + 
stat_summary( aes(group = Analyzer),  fun.y = "mean", geom = "point",
        shape = 20, size = 2, color = "red", fill = "red", position = position_dodge(width = .75) )
```